# Who are the leaders of the Jehovah's Witnesses church?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, leadership, church-structure

I assume the Jehovah's Witnesses church has structure and organization for its membership.

Who are the leaders of the Jehovah's Witnesses, and what is their role? From whom do members receive guidance and counsel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The head of the Jehovah's Witness Church is known as the [Watchtower Society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_Tower_Bible_and_Tract_Society_of_Pennsylvania).

<sup>Sorry for using Wikipedia as a reference, but apparently the JW website doesn't give out much information on them.</sup>

On the official Jehovah's Witnesses website, we can get the following information from [How Are Congregations of Jehovah’s Witnesses Organized?](http://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/faq/congregations-organized/)

> How Are Your Congregations Organized?
>
> A body of elders supervises each congregation. About 20 congregations
> form a circuit, and about 10 circuits are grouped into a district.
> Congregations receive periodic visits from traveling elders, known as
> circuit overseers and district overseers.
>
> Bible-based guidance and instructions are provided by a Governing Body
> made up of longtime Witnesses who currently work at the international
> offices of Jehovah’s Witnesses in Brooklyn, New York.—Acts 15:23-29; 1
> Timothy 3:1-7.

The [information about the founder](http://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/faq/founder/) also helps to understand the organizational structure:

> The modern-day organization of Jehovah’s Witnesses began at the end of
> the 19th century. At that time, a small group of Bible students who
> lived near Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, in the United States, began a
> systematic analysis of the Bible. They compared the doctrines taught
> by the churches with what the Bible really teaches. They began
> publishing what they learned in books, newspapers, and the journal
> that is now called The Watchtower—Announcing Jehovah’s Kingdom.
>
> Among that group of sincere Bible students was a man named Charles
> Taze Russell. While Russell took the lead in the Bible education work
> at that time and was the first editor of The Watchtower, he was not
> the founder of a new religion. The goal of Russell and the other Bible
> Students, as the group was then known, was to promote the teachings of
> Jesus Christ and to follow the practices of the first-century
> Christian congregation. Since Jesus is the Founder of Christianity, we
> view him as the founder of our organization.—Colossians 1:18-20.

Russell founded the Watchtower Society, which is the head of the Jehovah's Witnesses Church.

It is very difficult to get official information about the governing body from sources within the organization, but if you trust Wikipedia as a source, they do have [more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Governing_Body_of_Jehovah%27s_Witnesses#Committees) (and in this case, Wikipedia does seem to have plenty of footnotes and supporting links.)

Among other detailed information, it lists the current and past governing members, how the members have been selected, etc.  As a sample, here's what it's got listed for current members:

Governing Body members

> Jehovah's Witnesses began capitalizing Governing Body as a proper noun
> in 1971; The Watchtower that year announced "The present Governing
> Body comprises eleven anointed witnesses of Jehovah."[82] The original
> members of the 1971 Governing Body, all now deceased, are indicated in
> italics in the lists below.[83] Current
>
> As of September 2012, the following people are members of the
> Governing Body of Jehovah's Witnesses[7] (year appointed in
> parentheses):
>
> - Samuel Herd (1999)[84]
> - Geoffrey Jackson (2005)[85]
> - M. Stephen Lett (1999)[84]
> - Gerrit Lösch (1994)[86]
> - Gage Fleegle
> - Jeffrey Winder
> - Kenneth Cook
> - Mark Sanderson (2012)[87]
> - David H. Splane (1999)[84]

Comment: Great resources, thanks. Do you know which individuals head up the Watchtower Society? How do they get to that position, etc?

Comment: According to Wiki, the elders in the Governing Body are invited by current members of the Governing Body. No other way to be in the Governing Body.

Comment: Nah. The Watchtower Society and the Watch Tower Society, and the International Bible Students Association, and a couple of others are the "legal instruments" of Jehovah's Witnesses. They're the official publishers, and they manage some property and land, do administrative tasks, etc. The head is the Governing Body. Traditionally, members of the Governing Body were also the board of directors of the Pennsylvania Society, but this is no longer the case.

Comment: (That's The Watchtower Bible & Tract Society of New York, the Watch Tower Bible & Tract Society of Pennsylvania, and the International Bible Students Association (registered in London).)

Comment: @TRiG: Was the "nah" to me?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81. Nope. It was to the answer.

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear as to what the actual answer is to this question. Is "The Governing Body" as specific as we can get? Since they're no longer the board of directors, what constitutes this body of people, and who are they? I can't find a lot on their website about this.

Comment: I found more, but only by holding my nose, abandoning my normal principles, and using Wikipedea as a source.

Comment: :) Thanks. I thought it'd be good to have it here on this site too, for reference's sake.

Comment: This could use an update

Comment: So there are congregations governed by circuits governed by  districts governed by elders.  The question though is, When there is an opening at a higher level, do the people at that level (or above) select someone to promote from a lower level (soviet style), or does the lower level select someone to move up (democratic style)?

Answer (score 3):

The Jehovah´s Witnesses have what they call a [Governing Body](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/s/r1/lp-e?q=Governing%20Body&p=par). A good reference on their beliefs can be found in [Chapter 14 of their publication Bearing Witness](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/lv/r1/lp-e/0/19252) where they show how they interpret Acts 15 as a being similar governing body in the early Christian assembly.

### Biblical Principles of JW Organisational Structure

Organisationally, Jehovah's Witnesses try and stick as closely as possible to their understanding of the first century model. They have congregational groups with male appointed members to take the lead**. All members participate in services and both male and female are considered ordained "ministers" and participate both in public preaching and teaching and congregational activities.

#### THE FIRST CENTURY MODEL

Was their some kind of central council that governed the first century congregations?

Jehovah's Witnesses attempt to reproduce the organisational structure found in the bible - they claim a "theocratic" system where all members are subject in equal measure to the biblical rules and regulations. What is that model?

Jesus left a group of 12 men "in charge" of the first century congregations. They were not democratically elected. Those 12 in turn, by internal vote, appointed others who in turn appointed men, such as the young man Timothy, as "elders" or individual who would take the lead in seeing that what the 12 men in Jerusalem decided was carried out in each congregation (or "church"). Even the Apostle Paul deferred to the decisions of these men that met in Jerusalem. (see Acts 15).These men were ultimately answerable to God, Jesus, The Word and each other (in that order). They were not above bibiblical law nor were they viewed as the "leaders".

> They did not have any special titles? (No paid clergy, no special privileges, no special garb (clothing), no special ceremonies. No "Fathers" "Pastors" "Holy Fathers" "Most Reverant", "Most Holy Reverant") but were considered "brothers" working to see that the group didn't fall apart and kept to the word entrusted to man through scripture.
>
> Where all of these non-elected individuals in a position of leadership "inspired" prophets? No, few if any of them were. They were ordinary imperfect men being used by God for a great work.

See also the following videos from the Jehovah´s Witnesses "Faith in Action" series:

- Part 1 [Out of darkness](https://www.jw.org/en/library/videos/#en/mediaitems/VODOrgHistory/pub-ivfa1_x_VIDEO)
- Part 2 [Let the light shine](https://www.jw.org/en/library/videos/#en/mediaitems/VODOrgHistory/pub-ivfa2_x_VIDEO)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. Thanks for taking the time to answer with relevant information to this question. I have cleaned up your post a little bit to make it easier to read and understand in the context of this question. We'll be happy to help you with some pointers for good quality answers as you go along. Hope to see you around.

Answer (score 3):

**Q.** *"**Who are the leaders of the Jehovah's Witnesses church?**"*

**A.** The One True Almighty God **JEHOVAH** *through* His only begotten Son **Jesus Christ** who has *granted authority* to Christ's "**faithful and discreet slave**" as THE ONLY appointed channel by God during Christ's Heavenly **PRESENCE** (from the GREEK word "**Parousia**" which is often *mistranslated* as "Coming") of the Last Days of this world / system of things to provide the spiritual food and oversight needed to nourish Christ's domestics here on earth (**[Matt 24:3, 45-47](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024:3,%2045-47&version=NLT;AKJV;AMP;YLT)**).

The "**faithful and discreet slave**" are the *remaining ones* *still alive on earth* ****viewed as a collective body*** / **group** / **whole** who have the true God given hope of **RULING** with Christ in his Heavenly Kingdom.

This collective body and in fact **ALL** dedicated and baptized members of the unified worldwide Christian Congregation of ***JEHOVAH'S*** Witnesses is theocratically governed by a centralized group of faithful, experienced, dedicated and baptized men known as **the Governing Body**. Consequently, the members of the Governing Body *are ALL part of Christ's "faithful and discreet slave"*.

We who are Jehovah's Witnesses therefore have but only **ONE LEADER** and that Leader is the one *specifically appointed* by Jehovah THE Almighty God Himself... Jehovah's beloved only begotten Son **Jesus Christ** (Matt 23:10).

In short, our Leader is Almighty **JEHOVAH** God ***through*** His appointed only begotten Son **Jesus Christ** whose leadership we greatly respect and submit to by remaining in OBEDIENCE to those *appointed* by God through Christ *as outlined in the Holy Scriptures* to take the lead among us (Heb 13:17).

*~ NOTE: I am a dedicated and baptized member of the unified worldwide Christian Congregation of Jehovah's Witnesses.*

Comment: Welcome to C.SE!  When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent).  This is a great first answer (+1), I like that it is referenced and clear.  I  like that it is expressed in your own words. And, I'm happy that we'll finally get some JW perspectives here!

Comment: I believe the intent of the question was to identify the earthly leaders or administrators.

Answer (score 3):

Update: Since this question was originally asked, two new members have joined the Governing Body:

**BREAKING NEWS | Two New Members of the Governing Body**

> We are pleased to inform you that two additional brothers have been appointed to serve as members of the Governing Body of Jehovah’s Witnesses: Brothers Gage Fleegle and Jeffrey Winder. Both brothers are anointed Christians who have a long history of loyal service to Jehovah. Brother Fleegle began his full-time service in 1989 and Bethel service in 1991. Brother Fleegle has served as a helper to the Service Committee of the Governing Body. Brother Jeffrey Winder began his full-time service in 1986 and Bethel service in 1990. Brother Winder has served as a helper to the Personnel Committee of the Governing Body. We thank our heavenly Father, Jehovah, for raising up such faithful men to share in the work of the Governing Body. We pray that Jehovah will richly bless Brothers Fleegle and Winder and their wives! (Source: [JW News](https://www.jw.org/en/news/jw/))

This is an announcement from the official Jehovah's Witness Newsroom, 2023

P.S.  In 2018 Guy H. Pierce seems to have been replaced by Kenneth Cook.
https://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/faq/governing-body-jw-helpers/

**UPDATE** ***February 2023 – Anthony Morris no longer a member of the Governing Body***

On Wednesday, February 22, 2023, it was announced at World Headquarters that Brother Anthony Morris III is no longer serving as a member of the Governing Body of Jehovah’s Witnesses.
https://www.jw.org/en/news/jw/

Comment: As to your recent update, I have not read or heard anything as to such an "announcement". Do you have a link to a source for that announcement?

Comment: @agarza I found the announcement on the official J.W. news link last week.  As User14 says, that announcement has been taken down. No reason was given for Anthony Morris no longer serving as a member of the G.B.

Comment: @Lesley Ah, I had not seen it nor did my Chrome extension notify me of the JW News post.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to build on the answers already supplied here. There isn't really a FAQ on the [JW.org](http://www.jw.org/en/) for the Governing Body. There are however magazine articles with information on both the first-century body and the one of today.

In the [July 2013 study edition](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/magazines/w20130715/) of the Watchtower you will find these 2 articles:

[Feeding Many Through the Hands of a Few](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/magazines/w20130715/jesus-feeds-many/)

[“Who Really Is the Faithful and Discreet Slave?”](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/magazines/w20130715/who-is-faithful-discreet-slave/)

A slave in that time and area was a different kind of slave than we perceive it to be today. A slave was sort of like a house manager. They took care of daily tasks that needed to be done around the home. The Governing Body is much like that slave. They oversee the dispensing of spiritual food, the preaching work, the building of Kingdom Halls, all the different Bible schools, disaster relief, and so on.

There isn't really a sense that there are people who are higher than others in the congregation. Really it's just equal people with different jobs and responsibilities. If you ever get the chance to meet a Governing Body member, overseer, elder, or ministerial servant I think you will find them to be very humble people.

The foremost activity that the Governing Body is concerned with is the dispensing of spiritual food for both the congregation and literature for field ministry. This is set up just like the first-century congregation.

---

I found another article entitled: [Loyal to Christ and His Faithful Slave](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2007245#h=13:0-14:594). That article deals with the faithful and discreet slave that Jesus talked about. It also shows what a governing body member is and their responsibilities.

If anyone wants information about us, that you can't find on the website, here is a research tool that has seemingly endless information on whatever you can think of:

[Watchtower Online Library](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/h/r1/lp-e)

It is an archive of every printed book and magazine we have printed from many many years back. It also will search the bible and publications for keywords. Very useful in researching.